# C# using memory mapped files

Tags: c#, memory-management, shared-memory

I was wondering, that what file extension do those memory mapped files have. Are they .dll's or something like that. Another thing is that can I use such a file, if I don't know its contents.

Comment: What memory-mapped files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)

> A memory-mapped file contains the contents of a file in virtual
>   memory. This mapping between a file and memory space enables an
>   application, including multiple processes, to modify the file by
>   reading and writing directly to the memory. Starting with the .NET
>   Framework 4, you can use managed code to access memory-mapped files in
>   the same way that native Windows functions access memory-mapped files,
>   as described in Managing Memory-Mapped Files in Win32 in the MSDN
>   Library.
>
> There are two types of memory-mapped files:

- > Persisted memory-mapped files Persisted files are memory-mapped files that are
  >   associated with a source file on a disk. When the last process has
  >   finished working with the file, the data is saved to the source file
  >   on the disk. These memory-mapped files are suitable for working with
  >   extremely large source files.
- > Non-persisted memory-mapped files
  >
  > Non-persisted files are memory-mapped files that are not associated
  >   with a file on a disk. When the last process has finished working with
  >   the file, the data is lost and the file is reclaimed by garbage
  >   collection. These files are suitable for creating shared memory for
  >   inter-process communications (IPC).

Answer (score 5):

> What file extension do memory mapped files have?

Memory mapped files can have any file extension. You can create a file mapping for any file.

> Can I use such a file, if I don't know its contents?

Yes, you can create a file mapping for any file without knowing its contents.

---

These answers are so trivial that I suspect that you don't fully understand what a memory mapped file is and why they are useful. I suspect that the question you should have asked is: *What is a memory mapped file?*

Answer (score 1):

A memory-mapped file is a technique provided by the operating system that allows you to access *any given file* as if it were a piece of memory. The OS just *maps* it to a portion of the operating memory available to your process.

Nothing more, nothing less. Hence concerns regading the file's extensions and knowledge of its contents are irrelevant. However, one would expect you know what's in a file you are trying to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of a "memory mapped file" is from OS/2 (the predecessor to Windows NT) where it was called, "global shared memory segment" which in fact is a more accurate term for it.

These are used to share DATA IN MEMORY across applications.  Such data can be saved to disk upon ALL apps that have hooks to it, have also exited (persistence)...sometimes needed, sometimes not.

For those that talk about reading in a file into memory, yes, you could do that, but WHY would you?  Do you ever need to re-read the same file?  If so, get what you need and load up some variables (e.g. configuration file).

This feature is really used for sharing DATA that is continually modified (by one or more apps) and read by one or more apps.   Much easier and quicker to do than using a database, reading/writing to disk files, etc.